# Why the 500 Internal Server Error all sudden

Tags: google-apps-script, internal-server-error

I have App Scripts on Google Sheets that I have across my clients.  They have a copy of it and individual app scripts on their GS.

Everything has been working fine until the last few days.

I am getting this '500 Internal Server Error' on a POST call to the script for no reason - on something that worked fine before.  To fix the issue I go and publish the script again which creates a NEW URL (that is nuisance) and I have to then take the NEW URL and plug it into the app for that client.  What a mess.

First why is this happening where these script URLs are going into an internal server error now?  This was not happening before.  I have at least 30 installs right now and growing.  And this error is just random.

How can I fix this?

Errors:

```
Level
Type    Description Date
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyJC-oXU9k5ijJc7vlvmT3xWNOZLBfl6RjjNqSU/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
14 hours ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
17 hours ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
17 hours ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
17 hours ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
17 hours ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
17 hours ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
17 hours ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
17 hours ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
21 hours ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
21 hours ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
21 hours ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
21 hours ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
21 hours ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
21 hours ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
21 hours ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyJC-oXU9k5ijJc7vlvmT3xWNOZLBfl6RjjNqSU/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
2 days ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
2 days ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
2 days ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
2 days ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
2 days ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
2 days ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
2 days ago
Error
Dynamic Block   
Server error: `POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmwyNADRdyBT6PUEBcuwv17EsQBTpTjfVwRbFpUw/exec` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Fehl (truncated...)
2 days ago
```

Code:

```
function doPost(e) {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[2]);

  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var sub_json = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

  var zip = sub_json.custom_fields.CS_Intent.toLowerCase() 

  var area = []

  area = check_area(data,zip);

  if (area[0] != '') {
    return buildUpdateCUF(area);
  }
  else
  {
    return notFound() 
  }
}

//=====================================================================================================
//  Pull the City Name and State Name from Google Sheets if we find a match to the zip code entered 
//=====================================================================================================

function check_area(data,zip) {

  var areaName = '';
  var areaState = '';

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

    var zipCode = data[i][0].toString()

    if (zip.indexOf(zipCode)>-1) {
      areaName =  data[i][1]
      areaState =  data[i][2]
    }

    var cityName = data[i][1].toString().toLowerCase() 

    if (zip.indexOf(cityName)>-1) {
      areaName =  data[i][1]
      areaState =  data[i][2]
    }

  }
  return [areaName,areaState] 
}


//=====================================================================================================
//  Build the ManyChat Actions JSON to Add the Tag and update CUFs
//=====================================================================================================


function buildUpdateCUF(area) {
  var output = JSON.stringify({
  version: "v2",
  content: {
    "actions": [  
         { 
          "action": "add_tag",
          "tag_name": "CS_Service_Area_Yes"
         },
         {
          "action": "set_field_value",
          "field_name": "CS_City",
          "value": area[0]
         },
         {
          "action": "set_field_value",
          "field_name": "CS_State",
          "value": area[1]
         }
     ] 
  }
});

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(output).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//  Could not find zip code in service area
//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


function notFound() {
  var output = JSON.stringify({
    version: "v2",
    content: {
    "actions": [  
         { 
          "action": "remove_tag",
          "tag_name": "CS_Service_Area_Yes"
         }
     ] 
  }
});
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(output).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Comment: Can you check if the scripts were automatically updated to V8?

Comment: 500 Error covers the broad range of were not sure what went wrong but something did.  It may not be your fault at all.  You should do some research on this yourself before jumping to conclusions.  Something I do far too often.  I doubt that anyone will be able to give you a definitive answer.  Certainly not without  your code but possibly not even with it.

Comment: Could you please provide the code you're using in your Web App or a reproducible sample? Also, which deployment options are you using?

Comment: The scripts were NOT auto updated to V8.  It keeps asking me if I want to and I dismiss every time.  This all started to happen when they introduced the V8.  These scripts have runs for MONTHS with no issues and now this.

Comment: I can provide the code.  But if it was the code why does it work fine on some installs ALL THE TIME and then others it works for 4 times and breaks.  To fix all I need to do is redeploy the web app - gives me a new URL and thing work fine again.

I am sure this has something to do with the V8 rollout - seems very suspicious that it started when they annouced this.

Comment: I would add code but don't know how.  Trying to figure out how @AndresDuarte

Comment: @AndresDuarte Deploy as Web App.   Then I am using the URL in a external call.  As I said it works fine on a particular install then 3 times used - or 5 times used - then all sudden get a 500 error.  I have others that have runs for weeks with no issues with the same code.  I can fix it by Deploy as Web App again and get a NEW URL to run - works fine then.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan they were NOT updated to V8 auto - it keeps asking me if I want and I dismiss.

Comment: @AndresDuarte code below

Comment: @Cooper I haven't jump to conclusion and I have done research before even coming here.  this is why I am here.

It seems very interesting that this started happening when this V8 came out and started to show up in the script - aksing me if I want to convert to it.  The reason I am here is for help since Google said this is resource for help.  My code is below and I am 99% sure its not the code when a delopyment works for 30 clients with no issued but all of sudden one of them decides to get a 500 error.  But hey it cold be th 1% I guess.

Comment: This might be a bug/issue on Google's side. Have you posted to the issue tracker as a bug?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I have not.  Newer to Google App Scripts in the past few mojnths and haven;t had to report anything.  so where do i find  the issue tracker?  I apprecaite your help becasue I would have to say it's 99% becasue of this V8 upgrade because the timing of this fits.  I just fixed 5 more across 4 of my other accounts out of the 30 - it;s just random

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan  found it thanks

Comment: Welcome. Let me know the URL to your submission and I'll star it.

Comment: Are you allowing [redirects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#redirects) in your external requests? I'm not being able of reproducing your issue.

Comment: @AndresDuarte Yea you can reproduce it at will - it is TOTALLY random.  Today I have had no issues - very weird.  I submitted the Issue in Issue Tracker and got an email today saying sorry we can't help you since we can't reproduce it - that I needed to submit to Google Suite support lol.  Kinda of a joke but....  Anyway for now it's working.  I am SURE it had something to do with the V8 install and switch over

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Today I have had no issues - very weird.  I submitted the Issue in Issue Tracker and got an email today saying sorry we can't help you since we can't reproduce it - that I needed to submit to Google Suite support lol.  Kinda of a joke but....  So you can;t star it becasue they closed it - I apreciate the help! Anyway for now it's working.  I am SURE it had something to do with the V8 install and switch over.  Maybe the issues are done hopefully.